# How to get the latest document created by category in View using lotus notes

Tags: lotus-formula

How to get the latest document created by category in View using lotus notes @formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using @formula language, I assume you need to get data from the document and not the NotesDocument object (for which you would need to write LotusScript).

If this is the case, I would suggest using `@DbLookup` function with a hidden view (view name surrounded in parentheses) with first sorted column - the category you'll use and second sorted column - the function `@Created`, sorted descending, so the first matching document is the most-recent one.

You can use the `@DbLookup` to retrieve any non rich-text field from the document, or a pre-calculated value from the third (fourth, etc.) column (which could also include plain text, extracted from a rich-text field).

To be sure you access the most-recently created document that matches your criteria, the view would need to refresh automatically and you will need to specify `"NoCache"` in the `@DbLookup`. It could look something like:

```
@DbLookup("":"NoCache"; @DbName; "(myLookupView)"; "category"; 3)
```

Does this help you achieve what you're trying to do?

Comment: Actually I don't want the view to be invisible. It should be visible since I need this for report. I there is anyway to use the invisible view to a visible view to display the data that I want, i think the problem was solved. So is this possible?

Comment: @user335160 '@DbLookup' works with both visible and hidden views. The benefit of **not** making the view part of the UI of the database is that you (or another developer) are less likely to break the functionality later on by modifying the design of the view while forgetting or not realizing that a lookup depends on it.

Comment: Hristo- I will try this one and get back to you for the results.thank you very much.

Comment: might you have an idea about this also :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149879/graph-rendering-in-the-server-is-incorrect

Comment: Hristo- can you please give me a sample on how to use this in view (visible). I can't figure it out

Comment: If you have a view with alias "myLookupView", where the first column is categorized and displays the field you want to look-up by and the second column is computed with the `@Created` function and sorted in descending order, the following formula (placed in a button in a form) looks up the documents in your view based on the value you typed in the LookupCategory field and places the `@Created` date & time of the most-recently created document with the provided category in field named `Result`:

Comment: `listCreated := @DbLookup("":"NoCache"; @DbName; "myLookupView"; LookupCategory; 2);`  
`FIELD Result := @Subset(listCreated; 1);`

Comment: You can find more information in the [help for @DbLookup](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DBLOOKUP_NOTES_DATABASES.html). If your lookup doesn't seem to work correctly, be sure to read all the fine print! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, with pure @Formula I don't think you can.

Off the top of my head, I'd look into writing a LotusScript agent called with @Command([ToolsRunMacro]) that does it with a ViewNavigator and returns a result directly or in the environment (notes.ini) where it is picked up by the @formula.