# Graph rendering in the server is incorrect

Tags: lotus-notes

I have an application deployed in the development server (notes client). The application composed a function to export the data in the local machine of the user along with the graph generation. My problem is, when the data are exported, the rendering of graph is incorrect (in the server), but when I run it in my local machine the graph rendering is fine.
I used MS 2007 in my local machine but in the development server there is NO MS Office installed.Is there any way to do this? Here is the code below.

```
Dim s As New notessession
Dim db As notesdatabase
Set db= s.currentdatabase
Dim uiw As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim otherdoc As NotesDocument
Dim otherview As NotesView
Dim othercol As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim ViewNav As NotesViewNavigator
Dim entry As notesViewEntry

Dim tempdoc As notesdocument

Dim uiv As notesuiview
Set uiv = uiw.currentview
Dim VName As String
VName = uiv.ViewName

'if it is R4 then viewalias doesn't work so use
'environment variable stashed in the post open event
If Instr(s.Notesversion, "Release 4") Then
    currentviewname = s.getenvironmentstring("Tracking")
    If currentviewname="" Then
        Msgbox "View not exist."
        End
    End If
    Call s.setenvironmentvar("Tracking","")
Elseif uiv.viewalias <> "" Then 'use alias if it isn't blank
    currentviewname = uiv.viewalias
Else ' use name
    currentviewname = uiv.viewname
End If

'Get the view
Set otherview = db.GetView(currentviewname)
If otherview Is Nothing Then
    Messagebox "Could not open the view. """ & currentviewname & """"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check if it is for all documents or only selected
Set othercol = db.unprocesseddocuments
If othercol.count >1 Then 'if more than one doc selected then confirm
    resp = Messagebox("Do you want to export only the " & _
    "selected " & othercol.count & " documents?", 36, "Selected only?" )
    If resp=6 Then
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    Messagebox "Exporting all rows. (To export only selected " & _
    "rows tick those required in the left margin first.)"
End If '6= yes

Dim object As NotesEmbeddedObject
Dim xlApp As Variant
Dim oWorkbook As Variant

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True 'set to visible, this can be moved to the end if you wish

Set oworkbook = xlApp.Workbooks 'handle to Workbook
oworkbook.Add

'Stick out the column headers
hcolmn=1
Forall c In otherview.Columns
    xlApp.cells(1,hcolmn) = c.title
    hcolmn=hcolmn+1
End Forall

row=2

Dim vc As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim seldoc As notesdocument
Dim view As notesview
Set view = db.GetView(VName)
Set vc = view.AllEntries

If resp=6 Then
    Set seldoc = othercol.GetFirstDocument
    While Not seldoc Is Nothing
        Set entry = vc.GetEntry(selDoc)
        Print "Entry " entry.noteID " from document " selDoc.noteID '<--- new line
        'Msgbox row
        For colmn = 0 To Ubound(entry.ColumnValues)
            col% = col% + 1
            xlApp.cells(row,colmn+1) = entry.columnvalues(colmn)
        Next

        row=row+1
        Set seldoc = othercol.GetNextDocument(seldoc)
    Wend
Else ' all documents
    Set otherdoc = otherview.GetFirstDocument
    While Not otherdoc Is Nothing
        For colmn = 0 To Ubound(otherview.Columns)
            xlApp.cells(row,colmn+1) = otherdoc.columnvalues(colmn)
        Next
        row=row+1
        Set otherdoc = otherview.GetNextDocument(otherdoc)
    Wend
End If

'this highlights the headings
xlApp.application.Rows("1:1").Select
With xlApp.application.Selection.Font
    .bold = True
    .ColorIndex = 48
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 10
End With

'this freezes the panes
xlApp.application.Rows("2:2").Select
xlApp.application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

xlChartType = 51
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add

With xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
    .Name = "Chart"
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Total Submissions Received per Month"
    .Axes("1").HasTitle = True 'xlCategory = x axis
    .Axes("1").AxisTitle.Text = "Month"
    .Axes("1").AxisTitle.AutoScaleFont = True
    .Axes("1").AxisTitle.Font.Size = 8
    .Axes("2").HasTitle = True 'xlValue = y axis
    .Axes("2").AxisTitle.Text = "No. of Submission"
    .Axes("2").AxisTitle.AutoScaleFont = True
    .Axes("2").AxisTitle.Font.Size = 8
    .ChartType = xlChartType
    .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = "0"
    .PlotBy = "1" '2 = Column Plot
    .SetSourceData xlApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1","N6")
End With
```

Comment: Are you seriously expecting to encounter R4 clients? It's over 8 years since 4.6 was End Of Life.

Comment: How exactly is the rendering of the graph incorrect?

Comment: 2 questions.. How are you calling this code, Action button or via an agent ? Can you say how it's not rendering correctly, are you getting an error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line and it works fine even there is no excel installed on the server.
change SetSourceData xlApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1","N6") to SetSourceData xlApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1","N" & row-1)

Comment: As Hristo points out, you are confused as to where the code is running. Even when you access a databases on a server, this code would be transferred to your local machine and executed there.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you instantiate new `NotesUIWorkspace` means that the agent does **not** run on the server. So you should probably ask about the version of Excel on the computers of other users, who run the code. Note that the agent would only run on the server if it is scheduled or if you make it run on the server using `notesAgent.RunOnServer( [ noteID$ ] )`.